# How to add a modal which then opens a ctools modal?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to set up a modal that opens a ctools modal from inside it. IOW the user sees the first modal, clicks on a button inside that modal and it opens a second modal on top of the first modal. Then when the second modal's work is done, it closes and user can still see the first modal.

I understand that ctools is limited to one modal at a time according to [this DO issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2016899). My second modal is a ctools modal. I tried to set up a jQuery modal and a bootstrap modal as the first modal, but closing the second ctools modal always closes my first modal.

Any pointers as to where I can find a workable solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any pointers as to where I can find a workable solution to this?

If you know jQuery and CSS you can create your own custom modal. Modal one has div id of `modal-1` and for two `modal-2`.

use the `z-index` css property, and make sure modal 2 is higher than 1, so it displays on top:

```
#modal-2 { z-index: 10; }
#modal-1 { z-index: 5; }
```

Use CSS to center the div, so it appears in the middle of the page, [like this](http://dabblet.com/gist/2872671). Probably better to use `fixed` position rather than `absolute`, up to you.

Then with jQuery use the `.click()` function

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) 

      $( "#some-show-button" ).click(function() {
        $('#modal-1').fadeIn();
      });

      $( "#some-x-button", "#some-submit-button").click(function() {
        $('#modal-1').fadeOut();
      });

      $("#some-other-show-button").click(function() {
        $('#modal-2').fadeIn();
      });

      $( "#some-other-x-button", "#some-other-submit-button").click(function() {
        $('#modal-2').fadeOut();
      });

    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Unfortunately I don't have a choice with the second modal - it has to be a ctools modal (I am using the [Scald module](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald) and their in-line atom handling is done with ctools). How can I change my second modal (the ctools modal) properties to give it the z-index?

Comment: @longboardnode the z-index is just CSS. So all you have to do is find the id or class that wraps the c-tools modal (by inspecting element with your browser) and give it a higher z-index, than your other modal and add it to your theme's style.css file.

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I didn't really have to change the ctools modal z-index, just give my jQuery modal a z-index that is low enough to be below ctools yet display over my content - in my case the first modal worked with `z-index:10;`